Optimization over space of discrete functions on a graph
I recently stumbled upon a problem of the following kind.
Problem: Let $G=(V,E)$ be a finite undirected graph, where $V=\{v_1, \dots, v_K\}$ is the set of vertices.  Let $L = \{l_1, \dots, l_N\}$ be a finite set of labels. Let's call labeling any function $f\colon V \rightarrow L$ that assign a label to each vertex. Let $C$ be a cost function on the set of labelings such that for every labeling $f$ we have
$$
C(f) = \sum_{i = 1}^K b(f(V_i)) + \sum_{i, j = 1}^K A_{ij} c(f(V_i), f(V_j)),
$$
where $b\colon L \to \mathbb{R}$, $c:L \times L \to \mathbb{R}$ and $A$ is the adjacency matrix of the graph $G$.
I want to find the labeling that minimize the cost, namely
$$
f^* = \arg\min_{f\colon V \rightarrow L} C(f).
$$
Question : What kind of optimization methods would be more appropriate for this class of problems? I guess that some sort of genetic algorithm would be a good starting point.
I imagine that this kind of problems is the subject of study of some subfield of combinatorial optimization. I do not know anything about it I'd really appreciate any resources that could be useful to study this class of problems.

You'd need to be more specific about the cost function you have in mind for this to be answerable.

What exactly is your question? Are you looking for an algorithm to solve the problem?  If so, as Brandon du Preez says, you need to provide some structure for $C$.  Even specifying $C$ takes exponential space if you don't make any assumptions on it.

Please proof-read your question in the future.  I spotted one or two typos.  I have corrected them, but in the future, I encourage you to proof-read your question after posting to make sure it appears corectly.

Thanks @D.W. ! I agree. The question is still too vague and poorly written. I will properly edit it later today and I will be more specific about the kind of cost function I have in mind.

Please don't use "EDIT: more information".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters this post for the first time, and is self-contained.  Our goal is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful for others in the future.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  Can I encourage you to revise it accordingly?

What does $V_i$ represent?  Please define all notation.  In $V_i$, why does $i$ range over $1..N$ where $N$ is the number of labels?  Are you assuming that the number of vertices is equal to the number of labels?

Ups sorry! That was a typo!
